# How can I make my output exclude an element if it equals to zero?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I created this code with the help of Stack Overflow users.

```
def get_name(string):
    return string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")

def gnames(input_list: list):
    output = {}
    for entry in input_list:
        if '->' in entry:
            names = entry.split('->')
            output[names[1]] = output[names[0]]
            output[names[0]] = 0
        else:
            name = get_name(entry)
            if name not in output:
                output[name] = 0
            if "++" in entry:
                output[name] += 1
            if "--" in entry:
                output[name] -= 1
    return output
print(gnames(["Jim--", "John--", "Jordan--", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++", "June->Jim"]))
```

and this returns

```
{'Jim': 1, 'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1, 'June': 0}
```

Now this is right, but I want `gnames()` to return only the non zero values **negative numbers or positive numbers are fine**

so in my example, there's `'June' = 0`

and I want the output of `gnames()` to exclude `'June' = 0` or if any other person has a 0... I want `gnames()` to exclude it...

so my output in thiscase, should return

```
{'Jim': 1, 'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1}
```

How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also using dictionary comprehension, you can alter your return like so:

```
return {x:output[x] for x in output if output[x] != 0}
```

Description of what this does:

```
# for each element in output
#    if element['name'] != 0 then keep it
```

Full code:

```
def get_name(string):
    return string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")

def gnames(input_list: list):
    output = {}
    for entry in input_list:
        if '->' in entry:
            names = entry.split('->')
            output[names[1]] = output[names[0]]
            output[names[0]] = 0
        else:
            name = get_name(entry)
            if name not in output:
                output[name] = 0
            if "++" in entry:
                output[name] += 1
            if "--" in entry:
                output[name] -= 1
    return {x:output[x] for x in output if output[x] != 0}


print(gnames(["Jim--", "John--", "Jordan--", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++", "June->Jim"]))

# Sample output
# {'Jim': 1, 'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1}
```

Comment: `get_name` can be cleaned up using regular expressions.  `def get_name(string): return re.sub(r"[+-]", "", string)`

Comment: You may also wish to have `gnames` take a function as an argument allowing the criteria to be specified as a lambda, so the check for `0` isn't hard-coded.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary comprehension makes this pretty simple. If we start out with `gnames` being `{'Jim': 1, 'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1, 'June': 0}` we can write a dictionary comprehension that will filter out the zero value.

```
>>> gnames = {'Jim': 1, 'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1, 'June': 0}
>>> {k: v for k, v in gnames.items() if v != 0}
{'Jim': 1, 'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1}
>>>
```

Comment: why `v != 0`? why not just `v`?

Comment: Explicit vs. implicit. I'd call it as much taste as anything. I opted for explicit.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using .items?? Just asking so that if any python noobies see this, they can understand better

Comment: You can use `return {x:output[x] for x in output if output[x] != 0}`

Comment: As per the comment by @JacksonB, yes, you can, but using `items` makes the comprehension cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid an explicit `in` check to see if the key exists in the dictionary first else set a default value of `0`, you can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which is a `dict` sub-type which automatically sets a default value if the key is not in dict.

So your code could be simplified with `defaultdict(int)`, then with a sign to delta (change) mapping for a slight improvement, then finally you can opt to delete key from the `dict` if the result of addition is a `0` value; this can be used to **avoid the need of a `dict` comprehension** in the return statement altogether.

So now with all the changes added, the end-to-end code looks like below:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


def get_name(string):
    return string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")


def gnames(input_list: list):
    output = defaultdict(int)
    sign_to_delta = {'++': 1,
                     '--': -1}

    for entry in input_list:
        if '->' in entry:
            from_, to = entry.split('->')
            # Use `pop` to retrieve and also delete the key from dict
            # instead of assigning the value as 0, which is already the
            # default behavior if the key is not present.
            output[to] = output.pop(from_)
        else:
            name = get_name(entry)
            for sign in sign_to_delta:
                if sign in entry:
                    result = output[name] + sign_to_delta[sign]
                    if result:
                        output[name] = result
                    else:
                        del output[name]

    return output


print(gnames(["Jim--", "John--", "Jordan--", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++", "June->Jim"]))
print(gnames(["Jean++", "Jean--", "Jean--", "Jean++"]))
```

Out:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'John': -2, 'Jordan': -1, 'Jeff': -1, 'Jim': 1})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
```

Comment: I'm just learning dictionary comprehension and finding it quite confusing, but does this solution _really_ simplify the code? I mean, if you were to look at this with fresh eyes, how long would it take to understand what's going on compared to what OP originally had...

Comment: @JacksonB A fair point; but you will note I actually simplified a bit of the OPs logic from what I understood. For example, the `output[names[1]] = output[names[0]]` syntax was quite confusing, so I replaced it with variables like `to` and `from` to better illustrate it. But I also took quite a bit of time to actually understand what the OP was trying to do. In this regards, I don't believe that this adds undue complexity as compared to what was already present in the original code above.